# How to select from a commas separated parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

I have this table :

```
Name | Date | Para1|
N1   | 01/10| 1    |
N2   | 02/10| 8    |
N2   | 04/10| 7    |
N3   | 05/10| 6    |
```

I would like to select some name as parameter : @Name = 'N1,N2' and only the sooner parameter para 1 so as output i will have :

```
N1 | 1|
N2 | 8|
```

I tried that :

```
SELECT TOP 1 Para1 From MyTable  where  Name IN ( @Name)  ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Put the part IN (@Name) does see Name as a whole word when I ask for Name = 'N1,N2'

Any idea how I can do that ?

Thanks

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Similar question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5614275/183955), Update your where statement.

Comment: If you are asking about: How to parametrize the variable `@name` in the `in` clause, then see this post: [Parametrizing an SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Para1 From MyTable  
where  ','+@Name+',' like '%,'+cast(Name as varchar(100))+',%'
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL-Server 2008 or later then you should consider using table value parameters, rather than a comma separated list. Below is an example of how to create the type required, create the procedure and execute it.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.NameList AS TABLE (Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetNames @NameList dbo.NameList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  TOP 1 Para1
    FROM    MyTable 
            INNER JOIN @NameList n
                ON MyTable.Name = n.Name
    ORDER BY Date ASC

END

GO

DECLARE @Names dbo.NameList
INSERT @Names VALUES ('N1'), ('N2')
EXECUTE dbo.GetNames @Names
```

Answer (score 0):

@name is seen as a whole word because it is part of the string. you should sperate them by comma like this.
'N1', N2'.

i don't know which databse you are using. but for SQLServer. you can easily split @name string based on the the comma delimiter.
and in oracle. this is possible too.

if you are using SQlServer andyou can't do it tell me.
in short the problem above is that you did not split N1 and N2 using comma you just put it inside string.
it should look like this 'N1' , 'N2'

Comment: Yes please , could you tell me how to split the @name string on the comma delimiter ? I am using SQL SErver

Comment: @francopshenri, you will find what you are looking for in this post: [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you are using SQL Server 2008+ then as GarethD pointed out you could use Table Valued Parameter.

If you are using SQL Server 2005 may be you could try this out:

```
--SPLIT Function
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitUsingXML] 
( 
    @String VARCHAR(MAX),
    --If your delimiter is multi character
    --then change it as VARCHAR with appropriate length 
    @Delimiter CHAR(1) 
)
RETURNS @Results TABLE
(
    parsedValue VARCHAR(MAX)
)   
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml XML

    --Below line seems to get screwed up once i post it in Blogger :(
    --please use the line as shown in the attached image. Sorry about that.
    SET @XML = N'<Content><row>' + REPLACE(@String, @Delimiter, '</row><row>') + '</row></Content>'


    --If your individual value length within the CSV can be more than 25 characters
    --then you might want to increase it in the below statement
    --pls note it won't throw an error if its more than 25 characters 
    --just that it would truncate and show only the first 25 character :)
    INSERT INTO @Results(parsedValue)
    SELECT row.value('.','VARCHAR(25)') as parsedValue 
    FROM @xml.nodes('//Content/row') AS RECORDS(row)

    RETURN
END
GO


SELECT [name], date, para1
FROM 
(   
    SELECT 
        [name], date, para1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [date] ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM #test a
    WHERE a.[Name] IN (SELECT parsedValue FROM dbo.SplitUsingXML('N1,N2', ','))
) AS WorkTable
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Seperate each name with it's own apostrophes (').

```
SELECT TOP 1 Para1 From MyTable  where  Name IN ('N1', 'N2')  ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

This query will return consider 'N1' or 'N2' as part of the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT Name, Para1 FROM <table name> WHERE Name IN('N1','N2') ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Comment: No this gives only one value, '1'

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It would be nice if you improved your answer by a reference and/or a bit of explanation.