# Finding exact value from a comma separated string in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a product table which contains a field called 'categories' to save product related category ids as comma separated values. I am using regexp to search products from a category.

Assume there is record containing `4,24,1,31`
my expression is,

```
..WHERE categories REGEXP ',?4,?'
```

but this returns both product of category `4` and `24`

I just need to display only category `4`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why would you save relations like that? Why don't you use another table?

Comment: i was. but i have lots of products and every of those products are related to two or more categories. so it makes a little huge table.

Comment: So? This is the correct way to do stuff in database. Now you have to do REGEXP on huge table, do you think that is faster?

Comment: I thought it is okay than using a separate table. Oh i am confused now.Did this way make me frustrate in future?

Comment: You have limited yourself. What will happend, when you must find products that have: a) catId 1 and 2, b) catId 1 or 2, c) catId from 1 to 3, etc... Just make table "product_mtm_category" that has field "product_id and category_id".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use

```
WHERE categories REGEXP "(^|,)4(,|$)"
```

This matches `4` if surrounded by commas or at the start/end of the string.

In your present version, both commas are entirely optional, so the `4` in `24` matches.

Comment: Do you know if this method is better than find_in_set()?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.