# SQL QUERY LIKE & IN TOGETHER

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a column in table which has following values. Names are separed by comma..

```
   ProjID    Names
   1         Adam , Babita Tripathy, Alex, Mihir , Farhad
   2         SaravanaKumar, Shruthi, Arthi, Suneeth
```

I am passing input value to stored procedure to fetch values. The input value is multiple names. If input is **(Arthi,SaravanaKumar)** i need to get both the rows as result because ProjID 1 and 2 has one of the input names. How can i achive it. Please help..

Search Condition.

```
    IF @Names<>''  
      SET @condition = @condition+' ProdType.NamesLIKE'''+'%'+RTRIM(@Names)+'%'' AND'
```

Comment: have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611715/where-value-in-column-containing-comma-delimited-values

Comment: Tanknks, I am trying to create a search condition dynamically..I am able to create it. Please see the search condition in my updated question..

Comment: I need to split input names by comma and then need to create a dynamic search condition..

Comment: You should (1) normalize database or (at least) (2) use XML to store that array of names.

Comment: Sorry, i am not clear...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to split he input string

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID('UF_CSVToTable'))
 DROP FUNCTION UF_CSVToTable
GO

CREATE FUNCTION UF_CSVToTable
(
 @psCSString VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS @otTemp TABLE(sID VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @sTemp VARCHAR(10)
 DECLARE @tTemp VARCHAR(10)

 WHILE LEN(@psCSString) > 0
 BEGIN
  SET @sTemp = LEFT(@psCSString, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @psCSString) - 1, -1),
                    LEN(@psCSString)))
  SET @psCSString = SUBSTRING(@psCSString,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @psCSString), 0),
                               LEN(@psCSString)) + 1, LEN(@psCSString))
  INSERT INTO @otTemp(sID) VALUES (@sTemp)                   
 END

RETURN
END
Go
```

It can be called like this.

```
select * from UF_CSVToTable('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,15,55,59,86')
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72ab4/2)

Comment: Thanks for your idea, I found another way, Instaed of passing names, i mapped all Project ID associated with user. that reduced complexity..