# Select one value of multiple values from database

Tags: php, mysql

I store multiple values in `VendorIDs` field and I want to `SELECT` by using `WHERE` one value of my multiple values.

Ex :

Table

```
| OrderIDs | VendorIDs | CustomerIDs |
--------------------------------------
|    1     | 2, 3, 4   |      01     |
|    2     | 1, 2, 4   |      02     |
|    3     | 1         |      03     |
|    4     | 2, 3,     |      04     |
--------------------------------------
```

Code

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE VendorIDs = 2
```

When I selected `VendorIDs = 2` it will be displayed by only first of values = 2.

```
| OrderIDs | VendorIDs | CustomerIDs |
--------------------------------------
|    1     | 2, 3, 4   |      01     |
|    4     | 2, 3,     |      04     |
--------------------------------------
```

And this is what I want it should be displayed like this :

```
| OrderIDs | VendorIDs | CustomerIDs |
--------------------------------------
|    1     | 2, 3, 4   |      01     |
|    2     | 1, 2, 4   |      02     |
|    4     | 2, 3,     |      04     |
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611715/where-value-in-column-containing-comma-delimited-values

Comment: It might be easier if your `vendorIDs` had two columns ..  `vendId` and `orderId`  so that you'd have a single vendor ID associated with a a single order id.  Then you have multiple colums  .. "Ven id 1 - Order 2"  Ven id 2 - Order 2"  "Ven id 3 - Order 2"  So you can see we assigned Ven 1,2,3 all to order 2 here.  That's a multidemensional database.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, VendorIDs)`

Comment: SELECT * FROM orders WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, VendorIDs)

it's worked, problem solved thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have the wrong data structure.  You should not be storing multiple ids in a singe string field.  Here are some reasons:

- Numeric ids should be stored as numbers, not strings.
- Each column should contain one data item, rather than multiple items.
- Ids should have foreign key constraints.
- SQL has a great data structure for lists.  It is called a table, not a string column.

That said, sometimes you are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.

If so, you can use `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set(2, replace(vendorids, ' ', '')) > 0
```

Alternatively, you can use `like`:

```
where concat(', ', vendorids, ', ') like concat(', %', 2, ', %)
```

Comment: +1 I recommend a reading of Chapter 2 of Bill Karwin's excellent book [**SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming**](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557). Chapter 2 is available in the "Look Inside" on Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

If your column type is text then you can do a text match using the LIKE keyword with the string "% 2,%" (noting the whitespace and comma as a delimiter.  For example

`SELECT * FROM Orders where VendorIDs LIKE "% 2,%"`

Better still, if you're using these ID's to look anything else up, store them in a separate table and `JOIN`.  You can then use `Group_Concat(VendorId`) and a `GROUP BY VendorId` to aggregate the results into a similar format.

Comment: What if the result is the first result? Is there going to be a space in front of the number?

Comment: Good point;  You may have to use `LIKE "2,%" OR LIKE "% 2,%";` thus catering for 'leading two or only two'.  Again, its a horrible query hack which is better solved by an improved schema.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that your IDs are stored in comma separated format as shown, you could do something like this:

```
declare vendorId int;
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE VendorIDs LIKE CONCAT('%', vendorId, ',%')
```

This should work fine, but it will deny any index usage (starting %) and a table scan will happen (noticeable differences will appear when your Orders table is very big and your query does not narrow the result).

Normally, your `VendorIDs` should be stored in a X table, to allow indexing:

```
**OrderVendor**
Id
OrderId
VendorId
```