# How to write a hql query to search one word from comma separated words

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hql, oracle12c

I am trying to write a **hql query** to search one word **from comma separated words**.

**My input** is like `abc,xyz,par`.

**Expected result:** Should be displayed the matched record if any of the words matches the REGEX.

I tried with `REGEXP_LIKE` regular expression (Ex: REGEXP_LIKE(columnname, "value")) in hql but it is not working.

Please suggest me an hql query for given scenario.

**UPDATE:**
My attempt is:

```
SELECT emp.title 
FROM employee as emp 
WHERE 1=1 and (emp.title regexp_like (emp.title, :empTitle))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post some code of your try

Comment: SELECT emp.title FROM employee as emp WHERE 1=1 and (emp.title regexp_like (emp.title, :empTitle)). here empTitle is comma separated values. If it matches with one or more values the it should display the matched records.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611715/where-value-in-column-containing-comma-delimited-values

Comment: @udaybhaskar, I think it is not duplicate because I am asking how to write query on hql. Please provide me any suggestions.

Comment: He is using HQL and he may be motivated to not use a database-specific regex function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get away with just using `LIKE` and eschewing more complex regex methods.  Try using this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE columnname LIKE 'value,' OR
      columnname LIKE ',value,' OR
      columnname LIKE ',value'
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. There may be multiple values (Keywords search)